# background-color difícil de encontrar

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte site [Slide Show](http://www.funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index5.php)

Nele, existe (***apenas***) um **slide show**.

Na parte da navegação, existe uma tag nav que tem um

```
background :rgba (0,0,0,.5)
```

E tem dois `buttons` com uma imagem como fundo.

Essa imagem é transparente nas bordas. Porém, está aparecendo um fundo cinza claro que não encontro de onde vem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o elemento  por default tem uma cor de background.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para arrumar isso no seu css coloque a cor `transparent` no background.

**OBS:** repare que o `button` também tem uma `borda` por default, e eu não retirei apenas para vc ver que mesmo eu não declarando um `border` nenhum mesmo assim o *user-agent* do browse colocou a borda....

```css
.cor {
 background-color: transparent;
}
.borda {
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<button> com fundo </button>

<button class="cor"> sem fundo </button>

<button class="cor borda"> sem cor / sem borda </button>
```

Aqui tem um link para vc ler mais sobre a tag `<button>` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: ent]ão, obrigado. Deu certo. mas se você reparou lá no site, eu faço reset sem tudo no *{} inclusive nas borders. Obrigado

Comment: @CarlosRocha no seu site ele está sem borda mesmo, eu só aproveitei a resposta para mostrar que o user-agente coloca por default vários estilos em alguns elementos. Mas fique tranquilo que seu * reset* está funcionando, seu btn já não tinha borda mesmo ;)

Comment: Entendi. Sobre aquela imagem primeira que vc postou na resposta, eu já havia visto no inspector. Só não consegui entender pois aquela parte do inspector, sinceramente, ainda não conheço direito. Só conheço os css e scripts do inspector que são programados pelo autor. Nãos os que já são padrão. Vivendo e aprendendo...